# Python Pandas: how to read all elements in a list and retrieve the corresponding values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
loc     end_time            ts          file
TPHD    2019-06-03 16:45:30 43619.4375  trial.csv
TPCL    2019-06-03 16:30:00 43619.5520  trial.csv
TPHD    2019-06-03 16:15:30 43619.6774  trial.csv
TPBL    2019-06-03 16:15:30 43619.4479  trial.csv
TPBL    2019-06-03 14:43:45 43619.6982  mgrflash.csv
TPCL    2019-06-03 13:15:00 43619.4375  mgrflash.csv
TPCL    2019-06-03 11:15:30 43619.6875  mgrflash.csv
TPCL    2019-06-03 10:45:00 43619.6137  trial.csv
TPBL    2019-06-03 10:30:00 43619.6774  mgrflash.csv
TPHD    2019-06-03 10:30:00 43619.4690  mgrflash.csv
```

Objective: I want find the time difference between `end_time` and a specified time like `datetime.datetime.now()` for each location and file. For this I have tried as follows:

```
df_test = df.drop_duplicates(['loc','file'])
location = ['TPCL','TPBL','TPHD']
now_dt = dt.now()
for i in location:
    if i in df_test['loc'].tolist():
        t_update_loc = df_test.loc[df_test['loc']==i,'end_time']
        d = []
        for j in t_update_loc.tolist():
            diff = now_dt - j
            d.append(diff)
```

The above code is not showing correct result. In fact it is picking up `TPHD` values only. The output of the above is as below:

```
_libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta  1     140 days 02:55:06.056170
_libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta  1     140 days 09:10:36.056170
```

Ideally I want a dataframe as follows:

```
loc    time_stamp
TPCL   2019-06-03 16:30:00
TPBL   2019-06-03 16:15:30
TPHD   2019-06-03 16:45:30
```

How can I get the above dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

if i understood well, you can simply use:

`df['diff'] = datetime.datetime.now() - df.end_time`

Comment: Thats ok. But how to get the above dataframe. Especially why the `location` list is not being read correctly when running the `for i in location` loop

Comment: why do you need a for loop? in your expected output, why is there only one line per location? i thought you wanted one per loc and file name? please explain more how is the ouput df obtained

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `end_time` is a datetime object

`import datetime`

`df = df.drop_duplicates(['loc']).assign(time_stamp=lambda x: datetime.datetime.now() - x['end_time'])`